# Can DHIS2 be used for other development programs besides health?

Tags: dhis2

Can DHIS2 be used for other development programs besides health? For example: education or economic development?

Comment: Why don't you use their contact form and ask them? https://www.dhis2.org/contact

Answer (score 2):

Yes. While DHIS2 was primarily designed for HIS use, its development has shifted towards a flexible meta-data approach.

There's a beautiful guide available here:

*How to Set-up DHIS2 in a New Context?*
https://www.mn.uio.no/ifi/english/research/networks/hisp/integrated-health-information-architecture/ch-07.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can definitely be used outside the health domain. The system is designed to be generic and domain-agnostic. Successful implementations have been done within logistics, forestry, facility registry, surveys, education, food security, water and sanitation and social franchising.